# PHP Crystal Reports, or should I give up and use something else

Tags: php, mysql, pdf-generation, crystal-reports-2008

I'm needing to create PDF reports (both on demand and scheduling) for a PHP\MySQL site I'm developing.  I'm very familiar with Crystal Reports 2008 for some other software my office uses.  But I've never had to work at integrating it with anything myself.

The documentation I've found online is VERY poor, and I've never had much luck with com objects in the past.

Has anyone had any success with PHP and Crystal Reports (I've searched for a decent code example for 2 day straight and it looks like everyone is having similar problems I am), or should I just give up and look for another solution?  What other solutions are out there that retain some of the feature of crystal?  (Sub-reports, grouping, formulas etc?)

Comment: gah... crystal reports. Please just gag me with a pitchfork right now.

Comment: Although I don't share @MarcB's masochistic fixation with farming implements on this issue, I'd say it would depend on what you need to accomplish in the reports. You can look at http://tcpdf.com, which would let you create your reports in HTML and then pass it through an HTML to PDF parser. But Crystal Reports offers specific enhancements, so it's whether and what you need from that that's important to know.

Comment: You might have found this already, but http://mysqlreports.com/ looks at least like it's got grouping.

Comment: I just don't see it being an easy task (for me) to create these reports with HTML, I can throw together a report in Crystal in 10 minutes which would take me hours to do with HTML, and that convenience is something I need to maintain.  I'm not good at design so it's great that Crystal can take care of alot of that for me.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I'm looking for something free, at least for the time being.

Comment: Here's a link to the [Viewing Crystal Reports Using URL Reporting](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/boexir4/en/xi4_cr_url_reporting_en.pdf) documentation, if what you have available supports this functionality. It's easier to do XML/Soap web services than COM wrangling, IMO.

Comment: And the newer [Business Intelligence Objects OpenDocument development guide](http://help.sap.com/bobip#section6). I think "free" and "mostly comparable to Crystal Reports features" is going to be hard to come by without some offloading to another system not in PHP.

Comment: By this I mean [Jasper Reports](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/) and [Dynamic Reports](http://dynamicreports.sourceforge.net/examples/examples.html), but both are in Java and would require additional possibly significant setup, such as a server or service behind a Tomcat process, etc.

Comment: @JaredFarrish thanks I'll take a look at both of those as well.

Comment: Maybe [WebERP](http://www.weberp.org/HomePage)? It's it's own system (pretty customizable as well). I will warn you that for some reason the demo is in Portuguese, although none of the documentation suggests it's Portuguese only. I think your best bet is the BI web services approach if available. I did find several products of varying sophistication using "PHP free business reportings" as search terms, including RLib, which is a little lower level than what you're after I think.